# How to enable a custom ContextCache in Spring Test

Tags: spring, spring-test

In a parallel test environment I'd like to guarantee a new Context for each test (without forking JVMs). I'm bringing Spring into a Test framework that has some classes that maintain state - so a new one is required for each test execution.

The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html) elude to creating a custom `ContextCache` but I cannot find any more details on how one would do this.

I've been stepping through the Spring code while debugging a test and trying to figure out how I would get integrate my custom `ContextCache`. The method I have considered is almost certainly wrong, so seeking guidance on the way to do this.

The test framework is `TestNG` based, so I have a base class like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:one.xml", "classpath:two.xml"})
public abstract BaseTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
```

My current theory involves:

1. Swapping out `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` for my own implementation. Pretty much a clone of `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` except to control the `TestContextManager` it instantiates in member declarations. (it can't be effectively subclassed)
2. Subclassing `org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager` (it has default scope dependencies) and overloading various methods to avoid the use of the `ContextCache` it creates in it's member declarations. This would delegate to my `NoOpContextCache` that would not cache any contexts.

Using `spring-test 4.1.7`.

Things I've tried but haven't worked:

1. I've used `prototype` scope to no avail. The bean is declared as `@Scope("prototype")` and is `@Autowired` into `BaseTest` but I'm finding the same instance is being used in all tests that extend from `BaseTest`.
2. `@DirtiesContext` while it is doing it's job correctly, it's not useful when there are 20 tests using the same cached Context in parallel.

**Update 3hrs later:**
My swapping out of `TestContextManager` etc did end up working with my `NoOpContextCache` but was very inelegant...ie ended up with an `org.springframework.test.context` package in my source to get around scope restrictions.

I did however get the `prototype` way going by using:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyStatefulBean get() {
        return new MyStatefulBean();
    }
}
```

So that really gets me the outcome I was after, however I'll leave the question up as I would still like to know how to provide a custom `ContextCache`.